# Synchronous AJAX request focus wrong element in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

I'm having a strange bug and I don't understand what's going wrong. When handling <kbd>TAB</kbd> key in my application Firefox will give focus to a wrong element if I perform a synchronous AJAX request in the event handler.

I managed to produce a simple test case here : http://jsfiddle.net/aVeQp/18/

If you click on the result part and then press tab, the first two times it works properly (goes to the next cell), but the last time, it gives focus to the "home" element. If you change the query to be async the focus does not go to the home button.

```
var ret = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "",
            data: { action: "test"},
            datatype: "xml",
            async: false
            });
```

This does not happen under Linux but I have the bug with Firefox 16.0.2 under Windows 7 64bits.

I know that ajax calls are not working properly on jsfiddle but the bug happens on my own installation with the ajax call returning properly it is just to show the code and the bug. I tried using dhtmlx's AJAX request and the same bug happens.

Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong? I've tried a lot of things, it seems that firefox does not care about stopping the propagation of the event in this specific case.

EDIT: Seems that I did something wrong in my previous tests and setTimeout() is a working solution in the end.
But I still thinks it should work without this "hack" in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have the required environment to replicate but i have a longshot suggestion that might work for you. Try wrapping the ajax call inside

> setTimeout(function() { your call here}, 1);

See how it goes.

EDIT:

Binding callback to the ajax

> $.ajax().done(function (data) {   console.log(data); });

Comment: Won't this do the same as having an asynchronous AJAX call? I need to wait for the AJAX call to return before continuing

Comment: Is it a special situation where you REALLY need to wait until the call is over? Or can you do whatever operation you need to do by using the callback bind in my post? (edited)

Comment: No I "must" wait. At least I know I could use asynchronous AJAX query and avoid this issue. But my application is not designed like this AND I really want to understand what happens here.

Comment: I cant tell you what exactly happens here :) It has something to do with how FF specifically handles e.preventDefault(); However i tested a fix on another PC. http://jsfiddle.net/aVeQp/20/ Adding 'return false' after the ajax call fixes your issue. Curiously enough, if you add alert('x') anywhere inside the bind it causes the exact same issue.

Comment: Nope. Adding "return false;" does not work, I've tried it numerous times without success. Try reloading your version and you'll see it will bug same as before. But Thanks for taking the time to try anyway!

Comment: This one puzzles me, but it seems you're not the only one who has this issue. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=291082 - There's a lingering problem with e.preventDefault in keyDown events.

Comment: Yeah I've found all of this, I'm handling a lot a key events, either on $(document) or on specific input/textarea/datepicker/etc. I've found ways around each bugs except for this one. I'll have to change my application to handle asynchronous queries for this specific case.
I'll update the bug if I have an answer from Mozzila's forum.